# Grouping of API methods in documentation - is there some custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have controller like

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/user")]
  IHttpActionResult GetUser() { ... }
}

public class ResumeController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/user/resumes")]
  IHttpActionResult GetResumes() { ... }
}
```

Which on swagger generates output like
[image]

Is there a way (besides overriding default implementation by rolling out your own `ISwaggerProvider` or merging two controllers into one) to enforce the group name ? Something like

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/user")]
  [MagicalAttributeName(Group="User")]
  IHttpActionResult GetUser() { ... }
}

public class ResumeController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/user/resumes")]
  [MagicalAttributeName(Group="User")]
  IHttpActionResult GetResumes() { ... }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Once because it's the exact question i was looking for, and again for the use of `MagicalAttributeName`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a way - although there is no magic attribute - you can change default rules of grouping in swagger startup configuration in order to introduce your very own custom attribute.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
 .EnableSwagger(c => {
   c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc
     .GetControllerAndActionAttributes<MethodGroupAttribute>().Any() ?
        apiDesc.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<MethodGroupAttribute()
        .First().GroupName :
        apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName);
 });


/// <summary>
/// Forces method to be displayed within specified group, regardless of controller
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MethodGroupAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Group name
    /// </summary>
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="groupName"></param>
    public MethodGroupAttribute(string groupName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("groupName");
        }
        GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Route("api/user")]
[MethodGroup("User")]
IHttpActionResult GetUser() { ... }
```

Comment: thanks. i was able to adapt this to work at the controller/class level.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I get: `ApiDescription does not contain a definition for GetControllerAndActionAttributes`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/ApiDescriptionExtensions.cs (i.e are you missing using Swashbuckle.Swagger ? )

Comment: @Dennis It sounds like what you did is exactly what I am trying to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222584/how-to-change-controllers-name-in-swagger-ui.

Comment: Your missing a closing > in your code, it caused an error when I copied and pasted into Visual Studio, this worked however, c.GroupActionsBy(apiDesc => apiDesc.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<MethodGroupAttribute>().Any() ? apiDesc.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<MethodGroupAttribute>().First().GroupName : apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName);

Answer (score 35):

You could also use [SwaggerOperationAttribute](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/Annotations/SwaggerOperationAttribute.cs):

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/user")]
    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "User" })]
    IHttpActionResult GetUser() { ... }
}

public class ResumeController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/user/resumes")]
    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "User" })]
    IHttpActionResult GetResumes() { ... }
}
```

Comment: This worked - you need this now too - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974421/1447629

Answer (score 2):

I know it is very late but leaving the answer thinking it would be useful.
You can use the [ApiExplorerSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apiexplorersettingsattribute), this is your magic attribute.
Something like this...

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/user")]
  [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName="User")]
  IHttpActionResult GetUser() { ... }
}

public class ResumeController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/user/resumes")]
  [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName="User")]
  IHttpActionResult GetResumes() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be developing an Azure Function App while useing `OpenApi` annotations from `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi`, the magic attribute is the 2nd (tags) parameter in `OpenApiOperation`.

```
public class ResumeFunction
{
  [FunctionName("GetUser")]
  [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "GetUser", "User")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Run() { ... }
}
```