# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Minimal API / Swagger tags

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is there any way to change the tag for a given `http` method written with minimal api?

```cs
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

...

app.MapGet("/todo", () => "Hello world");
```

So that I can logically group methods in the documentation, similar to those that were when they were in the controllers.

#### Edited

I tried (hint from @Modar Na) `SwaggerOperation`, unfortunately it didn't help.

```cs
app.MapGet("/todo", [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "ToDo" })]() => "Hello world");
app.MapPost("/todo", [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "ToDo" })]() => "Hello world");

app.MapGet("/projects", [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Projects" })]() => "Hello world");
app.MapPost("/projects", [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Projects" })]() => "Hello world");
```

[image]

### Updated

As a workaround, I used the `TagActionsBy` method when configuring the swagger generator.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.TagActionsBy(d =>
    {
        return new List<string>() { d.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName! };
    });
});
```

See my [blog post](https://blog.burgyn.online/2021/10/13/asp-net-minimal-api-swagger-tags).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about [`WithTags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/openapi#add-tags-to-the-openapi-description):

```csharp
app.MapGet("/todo", () => "Hello world").WithTags("ToDo");
```

Comment: I get "The type 'RouteHandlerBuilder' does not define the field, constructor or member 'WithTags'"

Answer (score 2):

I think that all operations that share the same route will get grouped by default

but for explicitly defining the groups you'll need to use the [swagger tag](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/) which can be used like the this:

```
app.MapGet("/todo", [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "MyTag" })]() => "Hello world");
```

[link for controller approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175018/grouping-of-api-methods-in-documentation-is-there-some-custom-attribute)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried `SwaggerOperation` , unfortunately it didn't help. (edit origin question)

Comment: have you tried the approach in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175018/grouping-of-api-methods-in-documentation-is-there-some-custom-attribute#answer-34179838) ? @Mino

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Unfortunately `SwaggerOperation`  can't be used, but the idea was good and led me to a solution. See update of my question. Thank you again

Comment: You can use the new WithTags method https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ff1addd02d239d2d26f4648a06158727#add-tags-to-the-open-api-description-used-for-grouping