# ASP.NET Core 6 - hide minimal API endpoint from swagger explorer

Tags: asp.net, swagger

I have an implementation that requires the use of minimal APIs. But somehow, there is no way to exclude this from the swagger API explorer. In an MVC controller approach, we can hide endpoints using the `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)]`, but this is not the case for minimal APIs.

Code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("api/v1/endpoint_a", () => { ... });

// Hide this from Swagger API explorer
app.MapGet("api/v1/endpoint_b", () => { ... });
```

Putting the attribute in the endpoint is valid, but it does not work.

Code:

```
app.MapGet("api/v1/endpoint_b", [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)]() => { ... });
```

Any idea what I am missing in here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core 6.0 Minimal API / Swagger tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69356127/asp-net-core-6-0-minimal-api-swagger-tags)

Comment: I have tried it just now mate. It still appears in the swagger api explorer. I want to hide it.

Comment: Put [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)] at your controller to hide.

Comment: Hi @BerkayYaylacı, thank you for that! But I think It would hide the entire controller actions. I only need to hide 1, in the MapGet()

Answer (score 22):

Try this:
add `ExcludeFromDescription()` method after your endpoint, it worked for me.

```
app.MapPost("api/newUser", [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Administrator")]
        (string email, string password, int idUserGroup) =>
        {
           //Some code here
        }).ExcludeFromDescription();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer @Nuno Miranda. In a normal deployment, this will work. We have a custom Auth implemented in the API Gateway and our APIs are deployed via docker containers. So we cannot use this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IActionModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.iactionmodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to hide endpoints. Read article on [dev.to](https://dev.to/giannoudis/rest-api-visibility-control-57ph).